# Branch with different folder revisions (SVN)

Tags: svn, version-control

Is it possible (or a good idea) to have a branch with custom folder revisions. I mean that some of the folders are updated to a bigger revisions and other folders are not. I have created a branch and commited it but I can't get to a specific folder and update it from there after the branch is created.
If it is possible - how to do it?

Comment: This isn't clear.  Do you mean that you want to create a branch which contains a mixture of revisions from your trunk?

Comment: Exactly. The problem was that initially we didn't have `/trunk` `/tags` and `/branches` so we used to update specific directories when we applied updates. Now I want to create a branch that mirrors this existing structure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
http://codefez.com/creating-projects-in-subversion-trunk-tags-branches/

About what is a good idea or not, read the "Use a sane repository layout":
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/doc/user/svn-best-practices.html